# Puppeteer Select Table row/option

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, puppeteer

Working on some code that will select a table option that gets built out after an option is selected from a drop-down menu. Don't have access to github atm to check puppeteer documentation so I'm looking for how to adapt a line similar to
 `let optionValue = await page.$$eval('option', options => options.find(o => o.innerText === "Quality")?.value)`

`await page.select('#selDept', optionValue);`  in order to select the proper table row using either the id tag or the innerText of either "Stephen_Test" or the hidden cell measure id "1640". I believe selecting the measure id 1640 would be preferable so that I can also save that id as a variable that could be used elsewhere later on in the project if needed. I just don't have prior experience with nodeJS/puppeteer to know how to adjust this line to what I'm looking for so any help is appreciated.

**Current puppeteer code**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    
    await page.authenticate({'username': username, 'password': password});
    
    await page.goto('http://10.10.4.80/index-test-sh.html') //this is an intranet site for the company I work at
    
    await page.waitForTimeout(4000);
    await page.waitForSelector('#selDept');
    
    await page.waitForTimeout(4000);
    let optionValue = await page.$$eval('option', options => options.find(o => o.innerText === "Quality")?.value)
    await page.select('#selDept', optionValue);
    
    await page.waitForTimeout(4000);
    let measureValue = await page.$$eval('td', td => td.find(t => t.innerText === "Stephen_Test")?.value)
    await page.select('#Output', measureValue);
    
    await page.waitForTimeout(4000);
    //await browser.close();
    
})();
```

**Table is built with this loop:**

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {  
        txtTable = txtTable + "<tr id='row" + i + "'>"; //altered this to have unique row ID's
        txtTable = txtTable + "<td style='width:30%;'>" + arr[i].departmentName + "</td>";      
        txtTable = txtTable + "<td id='measureId" + arr[i].measureId + "' style='display:none; width:10%;'>" + arr[i].measureId + "</td>"; //altered this to include an id using measureId  
        txtTable = txtTable + "<td style='width:40%;'>" + arr[i].qmsMeasure + "</td>";      
        txtTable = txtTable + "<td style='width:20%;'>" + arr[i].measureSltOwner + "</td>";
        txtTable = txtTable + "</tr>";
        
    };//End Loop
```

**HTML generated after option is selected** (contains about 10 rows, just showing the one I want to select)

```
<div class="OptionTable DisplayScrollBar">
<table id="Output">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 30%;">Department Name</th>
      <th style="width: 10%;display:none;">Report ID</th>
      <th style="width: 40%;">Measure Name</th>
      <th style="width: 20%;">SLT Measure Owner</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="row0">
      <td style="width:30%;">Quality</td>
      <td id="measureId1640" style="display:none; width:10%;">1640</td>
      <td style="width:40%;">Stephen_Test</td>
      <td style="width:20%;">null</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</div>
```

Comment: Puppeteer docs are avail off GitHub: https://pptr.dev/

Comment: @AnthumChris how long does it usually take for it download for the first time? Been on the loading screen there for about 10 minutes now, not sure if it's meant to bring up a download dialogue or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After coming back to this issue the following day with a fresh start, here's how I accomplished the task:

```
try {
        await page.$("#measureId1640");
        console.log("It exists!");
    } catch {
        console.log("no dice");
    }
let measureId = await page.$$eval('td', td => td.find(t => t.innerText === "1640")?.id); // same as optionValue line, this time we look for 1640, and then return the id attribute of that element
console.log(measureId);
await page.click('#row0')
```

First, I set up a try statement that will let me know whether or not a desired measure/report exists in the table.

Next, I set up a `$$eval` that looks at the `td` tag type (I understand that that's what this part of the `$$eval` statement means now), and for each tag it will use the `.find` function to look for the tag with an `innerText` of `1640`, when it finds this, `?.id` has it return the id of that tag. This allows me to use the measureId in the future if needed.

Once this is done, I then use `page.click('#row0')` to select the corresponding row (I use `#row0` for the whole row, as opposed to trying to use the inner id's of individual cells), and this brings up the proper information for that report